# how i can make this delete query sqlite3 work in my python project?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, sqlite3-python

basically this is the syntax of deleting in sqlite3, how can i make it work in this def (function)??
for instance when i enter 2 i want to delete id number 1

```
import sqlite3

connection = sqlite3.connect("store.db")
cur = connection.cursor()

try:
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE store(id int, name var(250), price int,   manufacturer_country var(250));")

except Exception as e:
    print('table creation failed')

def delete_a_product(): 
    global cur
    global connection
    
    id = int(input("enter product id: "))    
    
    query = 'DELETE FROM store WHERE id=?'
    cur.execute(query)  
    connection.commit()  
    
    global products
    product_index = int(input('enter a product_index: ')) 
    lower_bound = 1
    upper_bound = len(products) 
    if product_index >= lower_bound and product_index <= upper_bound:
        del products[product_index-1] 
    else:
        print("Enter a valid price")
```

Comment: You need `cur.execute(query, (id,))` in order to tell the database which product to delete.  HOWEVER, there are bugger problems here.  I don't know what that last section of code is doing, but it certainly shouldn't be part of the function.  And `delete_products[product_index-1]` will fail because there is no such name.

Comment: You don't need "global" inside that function at all.  And you shouldn't do I/O in the function.  You should pass the id to be deleted as a parameter: `def delete_a_product(product):`.

Answer (score 0):

This is closer to what you were after.  This code still won't work as is, of course, because the table won't contain any products immediately after you have created it.

```
import sqlite3

connection = sqlite3.connect("store.db")
cur = connection.cursor()

cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS store(id int, name var(250), price int, manufacturer_country var(250));")

def delete_a_product(product): 
    query = 'DELETE FROM store WHERE id=?'
    cur.execute(query, (product,))
    connection.commit()
    
product_index = int(input('enter a product_index to delete: ')) 
delete_a_product(product_index-1)
```